# Top user leagues shows wrong top user for current year

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

We can see who earned the most reputation in the current week, current month, current quarter, current year or all time. There is this [great overview](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) for that. Also see the below screenshot.

[image]

What struck me as odd was the different users for the Mathematics site. So I clicked on the picture that is listed as top user for the current year, which led me [to this overview](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/69/year/math). Also see the below screenshot:

[image]

Here a different user is shown as the top user for 2019 when compared to the overall overview. I suspect the week or month listing to be somewhat volatile, but the difference between both users in this case is so big I can hardly blame caching.