# Error in top user - quarterly page

Tags: bug, reputation, top-users

I was just browsing through the top user page and might have spotted an error. See e.g. Tarun with 15.9k reps on the quarterly page.

[image]

In the monthly overview he has 351 reps.
[image]

If I am not mistaken, the quarter just started, so the monthly reps should equal the quarter reps.

For some users the monthly reps equal the quarterly reps, see akrun or Gordon Linoff.

**Concerning rene´s comment**, that quarter "is quarter", but month could be "last 30 days".
That is a good hint, but that would not explain the following stats.

Tarun - Monthly: 351; Quarterly: 15.9k

Akrun - Monthly: 4035 Quarterly: 4035

Comment: something with quarter being real quarters but month not being months but the last 30 days. There is duplicate for this, if not as a question then somewhere as a chat message ....

Comment: thanks for the hint. I made an edit. I am not sure it can explain the stats, that for some users month and quarter reps are the same and following your argument for Tarun the monthly reps should be way higher and for quarterly way lower, if i am not mistaken,...

Comment: Note that if you hover over the `Quarter` tab, @rene - it declares that the quarter started `2019-10-01 to today` Note that the month hover-text declares the same thing

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331950/top-user-leagues-shows-wrong-top-user